# Can I come to know how many people viewed and clicked on my Facebook ad?

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

I have an ad on Facebook and I want to know the number of people who viewed this ad and the number of people who have clicked on the ad. Is there a way possible for this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a few options at your disposal!

**Ad Report Stats**

The latest reporting functionality which has the most flexibility is the [Ad Report Stats](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adreportstats/). 
This report can be run asynchronously to process large reports, and has the ability to to aggregation and filtering.

e.g.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/act_12345/reportstats?data_columns=['adgroup_id', 'actions']&actions_group_by=['action_type']&time_ranges=...
```

Would yield:

```
{
    'data': [
        { 
            adgroup_id: A, 
            time_start: B,
            time_stop: C,
            actions: [
                { action_type: 'post_like', value: 180 },
                { action_type: 'post_comment', value: 50 },     
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Conversion Stats**

[Conversion stats](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/conversionstatistics/) will give you a set of data aggregated by action type and attribution window.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{adgroup_id}/conversions
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adstatistics/

use this kind of link using api

https://graph.facebook.com/act_{ad_account_id}/stats

Comment: You can explain it in a bit more detailed form.